# Unable to connect RETS server with PHRETS

Tags: rets, phrets

Can any one tell me what are the mandatory fields to connect using PHRETS?

I used :

`$config->setLoginUrl($rets_login_url)
        ->setUsername($rets_username)
        ->setPassword(getenv($rets_password))
        ->setRetsVersion('1.7.2');`

Comment: You got them all right there. What's the problem?

Comment: some MLSes require a useragent name and useragent password. check to see if you need those

Answer (score 0):

Some MLS servers require more parameters such as:

- User agent. When this parameter is required only a few user agent are allowed. Example: RETSMD/1.0
- User agent password. This is coupled with the user agent parameter. You MLS sysadmin should provide you with this password.
- RETS version. The version of the standard you want to use.

See the code snippet bellow for an example:

```
$config = \PHRETS\Configuration::load([
    'login_url' => $login_url,
    'username' => $user_name,
    'password' => $user_password,
    'user_agent' => $user_agent,
    'user_agent_password' => $user_agent_password,
    'rets_version' => '1.8',
]);
$rets = new \PHRETS\Session($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead above.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

$log = new \Monolog\Logger('PHRETS');
$log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));



$config = new \PHRETS\Configuration;
$config->setLoginUrl('xxxx')
        ->setUsername('xxx')
        ->setPassword('xxx')
        ->setRetsVersion('1.7.2');

$rets = new \PHRETS\Session($config);
$rets->setLogger($log);

$connect = $rets->Login();
if($connect)
{
  echo "ok";
 exit;
}
else
{
  echo "error";
 exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add 'RETSMD/1.0' for user agent like this:

```
    $config = new PHRETS\Configuration;
    $config->setLoginUrl($loginUrl)
               ->setUsername($username)
               ->setPassword($password)
               ->setRetsVersion('1.7.2')
               ->setUserAgent('RETSMD/1.0');

    $rets = new PHRETS\Session($config);
    if ($rets->Login()) {
    echo('Connected...');
    }
```

This works for me when connecting to MRIS rets.